# Contact Form 7 & Javascript - wait for entry to be added to SQL table

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, wordpress, contact-form-7

**CONTEXT**

I'm using Contact Form 7's `on_sent_ok:` hook to trigger a click on another button like this: `on_sent_ok: "$('#download-button').click()"`. However, what I am actually doing with the form is passing the values to an SQL table. So, what I am interested is not really the sending of the form data, but rather its reception within the SQL table.

**PROBLEM**

Although the `on_sent_ok` works as intended, the `click()` could potentially happen after the information is sent, but before it has been added to the SQL table. Other than adding a `wait()` function that pauses for X ms before executing `click()`, is there any way to make sure the entry has been added before the `click()` is executed?

Comment: The "right" way to do it would be to have a function run on `on_sent_ok` instead of a click - that function sends ajax request back to db to check all is ok, if not, then wait, then try again, when it is ok then ajax success is `$('#download-button').click()` - imho anyway